# What is the difference between GCC options `-shared` and `-mdll` (Windows specific)?

Tags: gcc, dll, linker, mingw-w64

The document describes quite obscurely that [the linker option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) `-shared` generates a shared object, and [the Windows specific option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html) `-mdll` generates a dynamic link library. I don't think this information gets to the point as specifying either one can build a DLL, but using the two options together will cause an error `shared and mdll are not compatible`.

The only influence on the binaries I observed, is that if no symbols are attributed `dllexport` (or anything similar), `-shared` will cause all symbols to be exported while `-mdll` does not.

More information: Looking into the linking step, by adding `-v` to `gcc`, I observed these two options will cause `--shared` and `--dll` to be passed to `collect2` respectively.

<sub>I have also found [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/mingw-w64-public/thread/532B58B9.1050003%40morous.org/), but the link in the reply is dead unfortunately.</sub>